# Facebook not asking for permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I'm developing a Facebook canvas app and I'm testing how the whole permissions thing work.

One thing is calling my attention and I think it's kind of weird: The first time, a user enters the app, Facebook sends the signed_request without the user_id and access token (as expected). Then my app redirects to the Login Dialog, so the user can authorize the app and give the asked permissions.

At this point something strange happens: Facebook is automatically redirecting the user to my app with the given permissions (and user_id and access token), but without prompting the user to give the permissions.

I have verified this behavior with test users and testers.

Is this normal? Is it possible to "force" (for testing purposes) the "ask for permissions" screen?

Answer (score 0):

It is normal on a second or later use of the Facebook app.

Remove the app's permission from the Facebook account before starting the app to get back the ask for permission screen.

Comment: This is happening in the 1st time

Comment: This is plain wrong and I doubt Facebook has a bug this huge. Security implications are just enormous (anyone would be able to access anything). Can you share a way to test this?